# Why add self instead of self.last_seen in sqlalchemy db (Flask)

Tags: python, oop, flask, sqlalchemy, flask-sqlalchemy

In this code the `last_seen` field is being refreshed with the current time whenever the user uses the site. However, in the call to the db, he (Minuel Grindberg "Flask Web Development") adds `self` instead of `self.last_seen`, which confuses me. I understand what the basic principals of OOP are, and I (thought) understand what `self` is (reference to the object being created), but I do NOT understand why we don't add `self.last_seen` in the last line `db.session.add(self)`? Full code below. . .

```
class User(UserMixin, db.Model):
    __tablename__ = 'users'
    id = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key=True)
    email = db.Column(db.String(64), unique=True, index=True)
    username = db.Column(db.String(64), unique=True, index=True)
    role_id = db.Column(db.Integer, db.ForeignKey('roles.id'))
    password_hash = db.Column(db.String(128))
    confirmed = db.Column(db.Boolean, default=False)
    name = db.Column(db.String(64))
    location = db.Column(db.String(64))
    about_me = db.Column(db.Text())
    member_since = db.Column(db.DateTime(), default=datetime.utcnow)
    last_seen = db.Column(db.DateTime(), default=datetime.utcnow)

def ping(self):
    self.last_seen = datetime.utcnow()
    db.session.add(self)
```

Looks very simple and I'm sure it is, but obviously I'm missing something, or haven't learned something I should have. If i knew what to google for an answer, I would have certainly done so, but I'm not even sure what to search for other than the principals of Python OOP which I thought I already understood (I did review). Any help would be greatly appreciated because this is driving me crazy, lol.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

He is adding the updated model to the DB. The model changed so `db.session.add()` will update the proper row behind the scene. I don't believe SQLAlchemy would allow you to add on the property of model because it wouldn't know which row to update

Perhaps an example would make this clearer. Let's take the following model:

```
class User(db.model):
    __tablename__ = 'User'
    id = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key=True)
    name = db.Column(db.String(25))
```

Now there are 2 very important attributes on the model for inserting/updating it in the DB. The table name and the id. So to add that model to the DB with plain SQL we would need to do something like:

```
INSERT INTO User (name) VALUES ('Some string');
```

This is roughly what happens when you use `db.session.add()` on a new model. To update our model we would need to do something like:

```
UPDATE User
SET name='Some other String'
WHERE id=1;
```

Now if you were to only pass one attribute of a model to SQLAlchemy how would it be able to figure out what table you wanted to add to or which row was supposed to get changed? 
If you just passed `self.name` to `db.session.add()` the query would end up looking like this:

```
UPDATE  # There is no way to know the table
SET name='Some other String'
WHERE  ; # There is no way to know which row needs to be changed
```

SQLAlchemy would  most likely throw an exception if you tried. As for why it can't deduce the model from `self` that is probably way outside the scope of an SO question.

Comment: Thanks for the help. . .As I stated, I understand what he's doing, what I do NOT understand is why he doesn't write `db.session.add(self.last_seen)` instead of `db.session.add(self)`?

Comment: Because last seen is only a property of the model. Behind the scenes SQL alchemy turns `DB.session.add()` into a normal SQL query to use with the database. That query needs to know which row to update/create so you need to pass it the entire object so it knows what to update.

Comment: So, you're saying if he had written it `db.session.add(self.last_seen)` it would have tried to add a new row (property) to the .db, instead of just updating the row we already have in the .db?

Comment: So if it needs to know which row to update, it seems to me you would need to tell it by writing `db.session.add(self.last_seen)`. Wouldn't that tell it exactly what row to update? Obviously I'm missing something, or not understanding something concerning "self".

Comment: `self` is a reference to the model class form within a method. Why can't SQLAlchemy figure out all that extra info since `self` is in the call? That's a question for Mike Bayer, the guy who made SQLAlchemy, https://github.com/zzzeek

Comment: Oh, wait, lol, I think I see what you're saying now. Let me look at this some more and I''ll let you know. Thanks.

Comment: Ok, I believe I see now. Had he used `db.session.add(self.last_seen)` he would've been trying to add just one attribute instead of a User WITH that attribute. I wasn't looking at exactly what we were using `db.session.add()` and the fact I've never seen any code in my limited experience that just used `self` by itself in a class. I can't even think of an example with a normal class (not sqlalchemy) that would duplicate just using `self` in a method. Can you think of an easy example where `self` alone can be used in a class? And again, thanks for taking the time to help me, it's appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

IanAuld is right-- but I'll make an effort to try and explain it in a long-winded fashion.

Lets put ourselves in SQLAlchemy's role, and lets pretend we are the `db.session.add` method.

`self.last_seen` is a `datetime` object, so lets pretend we're sitting at home, and an envelope comes through the door and it's addressed to `db.session.add`.  Great, that's us, so we open it up and read the message which just says `2014-07-29` nothing else.   We know we need to file it away in the filing cabinet somewhere, but we just don't have enough information to do so, all we know is we've got a `datetime`, we've got no idea what `User` it belongs to, or even if it does belong to a `User` at all, it's just a `datetime`-- we're stuck.

If instead the next thing that comes through the door is a parcel, again addressed to `db.session.add`, and again we open it-- this time it's a little model of a `User`, it's got a name, an email-- and even a last_seen datetime written on it's arm.  Now it's easy-- I can go right to the filing cabinet and have a look to see if I've already got it in there, and either make a few changes to make them match, or simple file this one away if it's new.

That's the difference-- with an ORM model, you're passing these full User's or Products, or anything around, and SQLALchemy knows that it's a `db.Model` and therefore can know how, and where to handle it by inspecting it's details.

Comment: I appreciate the effort, but I still don't get it. Nor do I know how to ask the question any more clearly.

Comment: I see what you were trying to show me now Doobeh. Thanks again for taking the time to help me, it's greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

Thanks, i finally got it!
So you are saying it is better to send the "`self`" which contains the entire model and `SQLAlchemy` than knows what to use as info and what to discard, instead of just some info where `SQLAlchemy` wouldn't be able to find to which row it pertains.
The "self" contains the `self.id`, `self.name`, `self.email` so `SQLAlchemy` can find the row and data it needs.
On the other hand, `self.last_seen` doesn't contain anything else except for the datetime object.

So, its practically just like when you edit an instance.
Lets say we create an instance named user

```
user = User(name="Eni", email="eni@gmail.com")
```

We add the user with `db.session.add(user)` and than commit.
But suddenly we need to change the email of the user `user.email = "eni1234@gmail.com"`
When we want to add the changes to the database, we don't just add `db.session.add(user.email)` but we add the entire instance so the modifications can take place like so: `db.session.add(user)`

Great, thanks a lot!

Comment: Please don't add "thank you" as an answer. Once you have sufficient [reputation](https://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation), you will be able to [vote up questions and answers](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/vote-up) that you found helpful. - [From Review](/review/late-answers/34728948)